# Crate SQL query using curl with basic access authentication

Tags: authentication, curl, basic-authentication, crate

From the [crate.io documentation](https://crate.io/docs/clients/rest/) I am told that an SQL query can be performed like this:

`curl -sSXPOST 'CLUSTER_IP:4200/_sql?pretty' -d '{"stmt":"select name from sys.cluster"}'`

The database I am trying to connect to requires a username and password:

[image: Auth]

How can I build this authentication into the curl call? I have tried several variants of things I found online with no success. The error I keep seeing looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box CrateDB does not provide any authentication.
Maybe you are running a HTTP Proxy or loadbalancer with authentication in front of it? NGINX? Try to connect to one of the CrateDB servers instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll have to ask the person who created the database I think.

Comment: You are correct. Turns out it's a Reverse Proxy using NGINX with HTTP Basic Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

The query worked when I included the login credentials as follows:

`curl -sSXPOST 'username:password@hostname:port/_sql?pretty' -d '{"stmt":"select name from sys.cluster"}'`